# HTML5 Prefetch Fails after first link

Tags: html, lamp, prefetch

I am getting a weird issue whilst playing around with HTML5's prefetch.

I have a list of about 10 pages, that I am adding.

```
<link href="/contact-us" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/directors-biography" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/patient-privacy/" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/patient-privacy/patients-rights-statute" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/patient-privacy/hipaa-basics" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/insurance-information" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/employment-opportunities" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/our-services/" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/patient-info/" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/health-info/" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/our-staff" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/patient-info/new-patients" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/about-us/clinical-research" rel="prefetch">
```

Now, I am watching Firebug to make sure it works, however, I am getting an "Aborted" status on /contact-us

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  This is on a LAMP stack if that helps...

Verified this also happens in Chrome as well.  IE11 (suprise suprise) works very well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code or server, prefetch is handled and controlled by the browser, you can only configure it to follow or not the directive.